# How can I origin REQUST_URL when there is an anchor(#!) in url

Tags: php, nginx, vue.js

I'm using vue.js to build my page. and the url likes this:
http://host/collection.php#!/collection/571372d102334d232de8e680

Now I need to do some work in backend, where I need to get the collection id in php.So I tried to get the part '#!/collection/571372d102334d232de8e680' from $_SERVER, but the part is missing.

```
    <?php
      var_dump($_SERVER);
    ?>
```

Output:

```
 ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>string(59) "/data/pk_api/api.pianke.me/api/version4.0/h5/collection.php"
 ["QUERY_STRING"]=>string(0) ""
 ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(29) "/version4.0/h5/collection.php"
```

How can I get the part after '#!' ?

here is my conf in ngnix:

```
server {
listen      80;
server_name tapi.pianke.me;
set $home   /data/pk_api/api.pianke.me/api;
access_log  /data/pk_api/logs/access.log main;
error_log   /data/pk_api/logs/error.log notice;

index   index.php index.html index.htm;
root    $home;

location / {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include     fastcgi_params;

}

location ~ .*\.(js|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|css|bmp|gif|GIF)$
{
    access_log  off;
}
}
```

Comment: The anchor is not sent to the server.

Comment: @RichardSmith  Got it. Thanks a lot